# How can I send data from one Django application to another?

Tags: python, html, django

Here is my issue. I need to send a form from one Django application to another (on separate machines). Taking into consideration line breaks, this is how I post my data.

```
<form id="codeid" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="code" action="192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/">
    <input id="textarea_1" name="content" cols="80" rows="15"></input>
    <input id="thebutton" type="button" value="Submit"  onclick="document.forms.codeid.submit();" /> 
</form>
```

The form action i.e. `action="192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/` is handled by url.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    (r'^time/192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/$', comp2),
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In views.py I don't know exactly what to write to send the form to the other application. I tried to extract the data from the form and send it with the URL like this:

```
data=request.POST['content']
redirect('http://192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/'+data)
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/'+data)
tml = url.read()
```

but I lose the linebreaks.

Comment: Is `192.168.56.2:8000` the machine hosting the web page or the server where you are trying to send the data to?

Comment: Can you send data from HTML direct to second application? `action="http://192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/"`

Comment: yes 192.168.56.2:8000 is where i'm trying to send the data but it is seen as a static ip, so i use urllib2.urlopen(url) to send the data in the views.py file

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send data in better ways, for example by using an HTML form to directly send data to the destination server, etc.

Anyway your approach to mix data with the URL in the `urllib2.urlopen` line is very bad, and of course you'll lose line breaks and many other characters. You should encode your data before adding it to the URL, like this:

```
encoded_data = urllib.urlencode({'content': 'Hello,\nIt is a sample content!'})
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/?' + encoded_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. when i send it directly from the html i face the static url problem.

Comment: I guess the better thing to do is to encode the data, but how can i do it without writing the \n my self? caus the data is written by the client on a textarea.

Comment: You don't need to add `\n` yourself, if user pressed `<Enter>` in his input, then everything will be OK, You were loosing line breaks before because you were not encoding data.