# How can I keep line breaks when sending data from one django application to another

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

A user write a code in a textarea (HTML) I post the form like this:

```
<form id="codeid" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="code" action="192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/">
    <input id="textarea_1" name="content" cols="80" rows="15" type="text" onkeypress="return runScript(event)"></input>
    <input id="thebutton" type="button" value="Submit"  onclick="document.forms.codeid.submit();" /> 
</form>
```

It seems that encoding the data with `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` is not enough to encode the line breaks,

This is how I do to send the data to the other application:

```
def comp(request):

    data = request.POST['content']
    url = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/?' + data)
    redirect('http://192.168.56.2:8000/api/comp/?' + data)
    tml = url.read()

    return HttpResponse(encoded_data)
```

So when the user type a python code for example;

```
def current_datetime(request):
    current_date=datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals())
```

This is what's received:

```
def+current_datetime%28request%29%3A++++current_date%3Ddatetime.datetime.now%28%29++++return+render_to_response%28%27index.html%27%2C+locals%28%29%29
```

There is no encoding for line breaks.
I tried to capture the `<enter>` event from the keyboard and add `\n` to the value of the text-area but it didn't worked.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this question different from [How can I send data from one Django application to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12072850)

Comment: It's not the same thing in this post i need a javascript solution or a way to encode the line-break, in the post you suggested it is question of sending a form and i tried to encode the data in views.py but it doesn’t change anything cause the data is already encoded when posting from the html. I thought that starting a new question would be better

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to `urllib.urlquote()` the data before appending it to the URL:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote('\n')
'%0A'
```

Comment: urllib.quote() replaces special characters in the data isn't it? you mean urllib.urlencode() the data perhaps?

Comment: Right, special characters like '\n'.

Comment: But the '\n' character don’t exists i have to add it before it is posted from the HTML